# Add a line break for a long link title within Html.ActionLink MVC2

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

I have a long title and need to add something like a line break within the ActionLink. I've tried \r\n as well as System.Environment.NewLine...all with no success.

```
<%=Html.ActionLink("Long title goes here", "index", "Overview")%>
```

Answer (score 10):

You may try something like this:

```
<a href="<%= Url.Action("index", "overview") %>">
    Long title first line<br/>
    Long title second line<br/>
    Long title third line
</a>
```